# THREE.js | TWEEN.js | Rotate Camera smoothly

Tags: javascript, three.js, tween.js

At the start of the program, my camera looks at the point `(0,0,0)`. I increase the z-coordinate of the camera as I scroll down. When it hits 160, I want to rotate the camera to look at the point `(0,0,300)` where an object is placed. I used `cameraLookAt()`, but the transition was too abrupt. I learnt about `TWEEN.js` and tried implementing it. But it doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Please help.

```
  if (camera.position.z > 160) {

      var startRotation = new THREE.Euler().copy( camera.rotation );

      var endRotation = new THREE.Euler().copy( 0, 0, 300 );

      var tween = new TWEEN.Tween( startRotation ).to( { rotation: endRotation }, 2000 )

      tween.onUpdate(() => {
        camera.lookAt(startRotation)
      })

      tween.start()

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use an animation library for this use case. Yes, `lookAt()` will directly orient the camera towards a specified target. However, you can use [Quaternion.rotateTowards()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=quat#api/en/math/Quaternion.rotateTowards) to perform the orientation gradually. This method is similar to Unity's [Quaternion.RotateTowards()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.RotateTowards.html). There is also an example that demonstrates this approach:

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_math_orientation_transform

The idea is to compute a target orientation for your camera and then use `rotateTowards()` in the animation loop. The target orientation is `endRotation` in your app. You just need it as a quaternion. Try it with:

```js
const endRotation = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromEuler( new THREE.Euler( 0, 0, 300 ) );
```

Comment: This is a good answer. I just need some clarifications though. I need to rotate the camera, if the `camera.position.z` becomes greater than 160. I tried putting this in the `animate` method as per the documentation and other examples. But for some reason, no matter what `step` I enter, the camera seems to rotate 90 about the z axis. So what was horizontal on screen is now vertical, and the camera still looks at (0,0,0). This is the code that I used in the animate method. `if (camera.position.z > 160) {
    camera.quaternion.rotateTowards(endRotation, 50)
  }`

Comment: Any chances to demonstrate what you are doing with a live example? https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/

Comment: I tried the fiddle. Didn't seem to work. Please clone and run this repo https://github.com/RapidCompiler/my-resume

Comment: I can confirm the fiddle does work, however `camera.quaternion.rotateTowards(endRotation, <step>);` has no change on the camera.